# Flutter : Textfield

Tags: flutter

[image: Textfield with icon button included]

I know how to use standard `TextField` for use, but I want to create a `TextField` as shown in the image, Is the class used `TextField` or is there another class?

Comment: You mean the badges at the end of the Textfield widgets? Try using the suffixIcon property of the Textfield’s InoutDecoration property https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/suffixIcon.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Icons` and `hintText` according to your requirements...
[image]

```
 TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, left: 20.0),
                    fillColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    focusColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    filled: true,
                    hintText: "Enter or paste address",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)
                    ),
                    suffix: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0,horizontal: 10.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.person,color: Colors.orange,),
                          Icon(Icons.person,color: Colors.orange,),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0,right: 10.0),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    focusColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    hintText: "Amount",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)
                    ),
                    suffix: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0,horizontal: 10.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0),
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                      child: Text("ETH"),
                    )
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `suffixIcon` in `InputDecoration`

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
     suffixIcon: //Your widget
     suffixIconConstraints: //Widget constraints
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a container and decorate that as you want and use Textfield as its child, add suffix icon

or

use a Container(having border radius and color) and inside Container use a Row and place TextField and another container(having border radius and color) accordingly.

```
Container(
  height: 50,
  width: double.infinity,
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.grey,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
  ),
 
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: TextField(
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          controller: name,
          autofocus: false,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: '   Enter or paste address',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
            
          ),
        
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        height: 40,
        width: 48,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.orange,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(width: 10,)
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: sure @YeasinSheikh, please check

Answer (score 0):

> **The Result**

[image]

**This is custom text field widget (*it is just a wrapper*). You can pass any border color, radius, fillColor, filled or not...etc**

```
class RoundedFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final FocusNode? focusNode;
  final FocusNode? nextNode;
  final ValueChanged<String>? onChanged;
  final TextInputAction? textInputAction;
  final FormFieldValidator<String>? validator;
  final List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormat;
  final TextInputType? keyboardType;
  final double borderRadius;
  final String hintText;
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final int? maxLines;
  final int? minLines;
  final bool isEnableFocusOnTextField;
  final bool readOnly;
  final bool filled;
  final bool isDense;
  final Color? fillColor;
  final Function? onTap;
  final Widget? prefixIcon;
  final Widget? suffixIcon;
  final Color? borderColor;
  final ValueChanged<String>? onFieldSubmitted;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry? contentPadding;
  final int? maxLength;

  final InputCounterWidgetBuilder? buildCounter;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final TextStyle? hintStyle;
  final TextAlign? textAlign;
  final TextAlignVertical? textAlignVertical;
  final BoxConstraints? suffixIconConstraints;
  final BoxConstraints? prefixIconConstraints;

  const RoundedFormField(
      {Key? key,
      this.validator,
      this.isEnableFocusOnTextField = true,
      this.inputFormat,
      this.controller,
      this.keyboardType,
      this.onChanged,
      this.focusNode,
      this.nextNode,
      this.textInputAction,
      this.prefixIconConstraints,
      this.suffixIconConstraints,
      this.onTap,
      this.readOnly = false,
      this.filled = false,
      this.isDense = false,
      this.fillColor,
      this.textAlign,
      this.maxLines = 1,
      this.minLines,
      this.onFieldSubmitted,
      this.prefixIcon,
      this.suffixIcon,
      this.textAlignVertical = TextAlignVertical.center,
      this.borderColor,
      this.style,
      this.contentPadding,
      this.maxLength,
      this.buildCounter,
      this.hintStyle,
      required this.hintText,
      this.borderRadius = 0})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        minLines: minLines,
        scrollPhysics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        scrollPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        style: style ??
            TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black, decorationThickness: 0, wordSpacing: 1.0),
        cursorColor: borderColor ?? Colors.grey,
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
        cursorWidth: 1.5,
        maxLength: maxLength,
        // minLines: minLines??1,
        buildCounter: buildCounter,
        textAlignVertical: textAlignVertical,
        textAlign: textAlign ?? TextAlign.start,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            errorStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            isDense: isDense,
            counterStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            contentPadding: contentPadding,
            focusedBorder: generalBoarder(
                borderRadius: borderRadius, borderColor: borderColor),
            enabledBorder: generalBoarder(
                borderRadius: borderRadius, borderColor: borderColor),
            errorBorder: generalBoarder(
                isError: true,
                borderRadius: borderRadius,
                borderColor: borderColor),
            border: generalBoarder(
                borderRadius: borderRadius, borderColor: borderColor),
            focusedErrorBorder: generalBoarder(
                isError: true,
                borderRadius: borderRadius,
                borderColor: borderColor),
            hintText: hintText,
            prefixIcon: prefixIcon,
            prefixIconConstraints:prefixIconConstraints?? const BoxConstraints(
              minWidth: 20,
              minHeight: 44,
            ),
            suffixIconConstraints:suffixIconConstraints?? const BoxConstraints(
              minWidth: 20,
              minHeight: 44,
            ),
            suffixIcon: suffixIcon,
            // labelText: hintText??'',
            hintStyle: hintStyle ?? TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade200),
            alignLabelWithHint: true,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            filled: filled,
            fillColor: fillColor),
        validator: validator,
        enabled: isEnableFocusOnTextField,
        inputFormatters: inputFormat,
        keyboardType: keyboardType,
        onChanged: onChanged,
        focusNode: focusNode,
        maxLines: maxLines,
        readOnly: readOnly,
        onTap: onTap != null ? onTap as void Function()? : () {},
        onFieldSubmitted: onFieldSubmitted);
  }

  InputBorder generalBoarder(
      {bool isError = false, required double borderRadius, Color? borderColor}) {
    return OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: borderColor ?? Colors.grey,
        style: BorderStyle.solid,
        width: isError ? 1.5 : 0.5,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(borderRadius)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**And here is a simple call your widget.**

```
 /// TextFiled Num 1
Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            // height: 55,
            child: RoundedFormField(
              fillColor: Colors.grey,
              filled: true,
              borderRadius: 20,
              isDense: true,
              hintText: "hintText",
              suffixIcon: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: 90,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                  ),
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(child: Icon(Icons.contact_phone,color: 
                 Colors.orange,size: 18,)),
                      Expanded(child: 
                 Icon(Icons.calendar_today_outlined,color: 
                      Colors.orange,size: 18,)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
           /// TextFiled Num 2
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            // height: 55,
            child: RoundedFormField(
              fillColor: Colors.grey,
              filled: true,
              borderRadius: 20,
              isDense: true,
              hintText: "hintText",
              suffixIcon: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: 90,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                  ),
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                  child:Text(
                    "ETH",style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.white
                  ),
                  )
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```